# move staff from one aws account to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, migrate

I have projects and all other configurations set up on one aws account, say A, and now I open another aws account B and am trying to move or migrate everything from A to B.
Is migration possible or i have to manually move everything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CloudFormation and related tools (CloudFormer?) to help with that, but deciding if that is more or less complex than moving manually depends a lot on the contents of A.